# Lista de Siglas latex

Tags: latex

Estou fazendo uma lista de siglas no latex, mais especificamente estou usando o overleaf para isso...

Estou com um problema, quando eu crio a lista de siglas ela esta vindo desordenada, aparece por ordem de citação no texto e não por ordem alfabética

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\pretextualchapter{Lista de Siglas}\@starttoc{lsg}}
\newcommand{\sigla}[2]{{\addcontentsline{lsg}{sigla}{\numberline{#1}{#2}}}#1}
\newcommand{\l@sigla}[2]{
       \vspace{-0.75cm}
       \leftskip 0em
       \parindent 0em
       \@tempdima 5em
       \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
       {\normalfont #1}\hfil\nobreak\par}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\loadglsentries[acronym]{example-glossaries-acronym}

\begin{document}

\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{abc}{ABC}{Auto ...}

\printglossary[type=acronym,style=long]
\end{document}
```